# How can I compress a large file on an already-full disk?

Tags: compression, storage

I have a full disk containing a large file that I want to compress to free up space. Most compression programs require me to have enough free space on the disk to store the compressed file alongside the original file. Although gzip deletes the original file upon completion, it doesn't do that until after the compressed file has been written. How can I perform the compression in-place, truncating the original file along the way?

I don't want to make a RAM disk to temporarily store the whole compressed file because that's a bunch of extra steps and because the compressed file might be larger than my available memory.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: @Moab if there turn out to be enough different answers for different OSes that restricting the OS choice was pertinent, then I've done a terrible job trying to find a solution to this problem on my own.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I asked as this question is off topic here, but some OS's have built in tools that are not off topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think it's software shopping if there are zero-to-one tools that can do the job at all. The question here boils down to "does this tool exist?", not "which of these tools should I pick?"

Comment: reworded the title to make it sound less like software shopping

Comment: @Sparr Well there are at least two of us who agree that it is off-topic. If you don't agree the place to discuss is in [meta] not in comments.

Comment: Your only option is to compress to an ancillary disc (eSATA/USB/NAS) and, if it completes successfully, delete the original file and copy back the compressed file. However, I see no point in doing this because, as soon as you use the space you have saved, you won't be able to access the file again (at least, not on the full disc), in which case you may as well keep it off-line. So your realistic options are: free disc space; or increase disc storage; or, if you can clear enough space, compress the volume, but beware that huge files (over 25GB) can give errors on compressed NTFS volumes.

Comment: @AFH your "won't be able to access the file again" argument is silly. If I do this to *two* files, then I can uncompress either of them individually afterwards. My use case here is for rapid recovery from disk-full states on servers where I don't know enough about the environment to delete any files safely.

Comment: Your question said "a large file"!

Comment: OK then. I'll be able to access the file *later*, when I move it off the disk onto some other storage. Or I can access it with something like zless/zcat without decompressing the whole thing. Or I can access it after I delete some other files, which I can't delete as soon as I can compress this file. Or... I don't feel the need to enumerate every case in which your objection doesn't hold.

Comment: No but... Yes! This can be done by using specalist software and a USB drive. Simply put, the exact same technique is used, other than the USB pen drive which covers the lack of storage on the main drive.  So, my answer is no but, you can do it with the right software

Answer (score 3):

In short.  NO.  Compressing a file requires a certain level of "fail-safely" kind of thinking.  If the compressing process fails, it needs to be able to fail in a way that you don't lose your file.  What would happen if the compression failed half way through the file?  There are many compression tools out there than can use a temporary folder (that is definable) that can be used to create the compressed working file... until the process is finished... then delete the original and finally put the compressed file in the correct target.

You will never find a file-compression tool that will rewrite on-the-fly the file as it is compressing it.

Comment: "What would happen if the compression failed half way through the file?" Ideally, I'd have on disk half of the original file and half of the compressed file, probably with a small overlap, and the tool in question would be able to resume to finish the job or to undo it.

Comment: @Sparr, that's not what failing means. If the tool could carry on with compressing, it would simply do it. Failing means that it's unable to continue. In case of failure it probably wouldn't be able to guarantee file recovery and you wouldn't be able to do it anyway, because you have no disk space left to unpack compressed files.

Comment: @gronostaj my response was based on a failure such as the process being killed, a hardware fault, a power loss, etc.

Comment: Failing will corrupt the not finished compressed file and if you wanted to remove it whilst it was compressing it would not have everything

Comment: The only time that failure mode would be definitely possible would be in the very first "chunk". After that, any future chunks can happen in increments of the now-available free space.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a lot of compressors, and I don't readily recall seeing this functionality being an available option in the compressors available.

In theory, something like this could be done.  Using the dd command (which is downloadable for Microsoft Windows, and bundled with many Unix varieties) could allow you to extract a specific section of the file, which could then be compressed.  Then, the original file would need to be re-sized.  Truncating from the end of the file might be easier than truncating from the start of the file.  (Whether that is true may depend on how software code is being implemented.)  If that is true, compressing chunks in reverse order may be significantly faster.

In practice, I've usually found it best to look for ways to clear off enough space to have both (the compressed and uncompressed) versions at once.  (Quick plug: I've become a fan of disk usage reporting: [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info)'s [installer](http://windirstat.info/wds_current_setup.exe), or [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sf.net) for something similar in Unix without Wine.)  Then, I usually like to also have space for another uncompressed copy, so I can uncompress what I've got and compare that to the original.  That can be quite challenging, and may involve multiple partitions/disks.  It can be rather challenging to pull that off, but if I do, then I can delete the two big copies, at which point I'm feeling a little bit less crammed.

Answer (score 1):

In MS File Explore right click on the driver letter, select properties, check 'Compress this drive to save disk space', click 'Ok'.

With luck there will be enough space to allow Windows to start saving more space, and eventually even to compress the file you are looking to compress on disk.

Please note - there may be a slight performance hit on all accesses to this drive forward.

Comment: terrible idea.  first off it would take hours to days to compress depending on the amount and type of data.  And the amount of space freed may be minimal.  Also, this slows the system down considerably.

Comment: imho its not a terrible idea, and who says that it cant do the job that needs to be done over night.  The amount of space freed is dependant on the type of files on the drive.  I use this method myself and I don't notice a performance hit.  It takes a second to down vote and answer - but time to think up a solution - it appears you down voted this answer within 5 seconds of me posting it.  What is your answer?

Comment: "With luck there will be enough space to allow Windows to start saving more space" Can you elaborate on how this works? Can it start compressing if there's enough free space to hold the smallest file, compressed?

Comment: I use compressed drives a lot and the CPU overhead usually more than offsets the time penalty of reading extra disc sectors. Not recommended on a machine running CPU-intensive applications, for obvious reasons. Note that you don't need to compress the whole disc: you can compress selected directories, especially where there are lots of text files. Don't compress multi-media directories: the file formats are already compressed.

Comment: Sparr - Can it start compressing if there's enough free space to hold the smallest file, compressed?  Yes. I just loaded up a 2 GB thumb drive to almost capacity with 1,505 files (file names of various lengths) each taking exactly 1 MB on disk space leaving < 1 MB free space overall. There wasn't enough room to copy 1 more such file; only 946 KB remained.  All files contained only the letter 'a' repeated many times.  I then checked the compression option, and with the space left Windows started compressing. Within 5 minutes the thumb drive was fully compressed - and now only at 7% of capacity.

Comment: Just to make it abundantly clear: Rob is RIGHT. Yes, Windows's Standard NTFS compression can happen in-place, meaning it requires virtually* no extra free space to compress files. It doesn't create any temporary invisible buffer files or anything. I just confirmed this empirically - I had a single file of 1.1 TeraBytes in a 98.5% full 2 TB hard drive. The file was big and pretty much just plain text, so even the relatively low efficiency NTFS compression can have a meaningful impact. The free disk space started gradually increasing immediately, and in the end the file occupied 41.7 GB less.

Comment: Not Off-topic IMHO. NTFS compression could solve it, and it doesn't appear to be going anywhere soon. And it's native to Windows, which has ~72% of the desktop/laptop user base. I hardly think this is "seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations". I understood it as: He had an issue, tried to solve it, reached a technical barrier, and asked if what he was trying to do was something feasible. Which it is. Requiring no additional software whatsoever, on the most popular desktop OS as of this writing. And the fact that I'm here 2 years later with the same issue says something.

Answer (score 0):

So I do not believe this is a "compress in place" solution.  But, it saves some work as it avoids having to go back and delete the original files after compression:

1. Right click in the empty space of the folder in which you want to host your compressed files.  Click New > Compressed (zipped) folder.
2. Select all the files to be compressed.
3. While holding down the shift key, drag them onto the empty, compressed folder you just created.

The files will begin compressing and will be removed from the original location once compression is complete.

Answer (score -1):

You can work around the problem if you have a thumb drive or external hard drive, you should be good to go.  Most compression programs default to the users temp`folder, or the system's temp folder.  In your case, this would be the full disk.  However, every modern compression program should let you change the program's working directory.

Take 7-zip, one of the most popular compression programs, as an example.  Under Tools\Options\Folders, you can set the working directory to another folder or drive.  So if you have a decent sized thumb drive or external hard drive, you can set that as the working directory and save the file there.

Answer (score -1):

If I were faced with this on Windows, had done all other disk cleanup options, and had no way of shuffling things around with an external drive, I would use the Compress Drive to save Space function and hope against hope that it freed enough space to tightly compress the offending file, then put the system back the way it was.  Thankfully I haven't been faced with that situation in decades, when large external memory wasn't easily accessible.  Not sure that this would even work with today's file sizes or SSD drives, but it's still a relatively* safe option to try.  Since it compresses small files in addition to big files, it might not have the same pre-allocation issues you're running into.

To do that:

- right-click the logical drive in Windows Explorer
- select Properties.
- Check the checkbox "Compress this Drive to save disk space" and click OK
  [image: Compress this Drive to save disk space]

* it may be hard to tell if the operation is hung or just taking forever.

Comment: oi, a downvote with no comment?  How am I to know if my answer is problematic or just in need of improvement?  I was tempted not to post this answer in the first place, made sure to qualify that it's something I'd try if I had tried everything else.